# volumes deleted from kvm, but not reflecting in guest vm

Tags: centos, virtual-machine, kvm

I assigned some volumes to my VM on kvm.
Now I want to remove those volumes. 
I used virsh vol-delete command and deleted those volumes. 
Still from the guest side,  can see those volumes!!!. 
lsblk, fdisk etc is listing those volumes. 
It is not a stale entry. I can even make files on those volumes. I rebooted my guest, but no luck.

list below shows no volumes in the pool now . Only it has boot volumes., but guest is showing already deleted volumes as well!

```
virsh # pool-list
 Name                 State      Autostart 
-------------------------------------------
 default              active     yes       
 pool_1               active     yes       
 vm-images            active     yes       

virsh # vol-list --pool default   --->boot volume
 Name                 Path                                    
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
 -------
 GOS_1.qcow2          /var/lib/libvirt/images/GOS_1.qcow2     

virsh # vol-list --pool pool_1   ---> I deleted from this pool
 Name                 Path                                    
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

virsh # vol-list --pool vm-images   --->just vm image backup
 Name                 Path                                    
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
-------
 centos70_vdisk.raw   /container/vm-images/centos70_vdisk.raw 

virsh #
```

From my guest:

```
[root@localhost ~]# lsblk
 NAME            MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda               8:0    0    3G  0 disk  ---ghost partition now
└─sda1            8:1    0    3G  0 part 
sdb               8:16   0   20G  0 disk  ----ghost partition now
sdc               8:32   0   20G  0 disk  ---ghost partition now
sdd               8:48   0    4G  0 disk   --boot 
├─sdd1            8:49   0  500M  0 part /boot
└─sdd2            8:50   0  3.5G  0 part 
  ├─centos-swap 253:0    0  412M  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─centos-root 253:1    0  3.1G  0 lvm  /
[root@localhost ~]# 
[root@localhost ~]#
```

But I can see from dumpxml command, vm has

```
<disk type='file' device='disk'>
  <driver name='qemu' type='qcow2'/>
  <source file='/container/pool/TEST.qcow2'/>
  <backingStore/>
  <target dev='sdc' bus='scsi'/>
  <alias name='scsi0-0-0-2'/>
  <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='2'/>
</disk>
```

But no disk in the location.

```
[root@localhost ~]# ls /container/pool
[root@localhost ~]# ls -a /container/pool
.  ..
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Can some one help me to understand whats going here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing a volume from a KVM guest requires the guest to shut down to take effect.

Comment: Did you mean guest shutdown from host or from guest itself? I rebooted the guest from guest itself [ rebbot command], but nothing helped.  Then I rebooted the vm from  host by using virsh destroy and then virsh start. Now it didnt boot. threw some error

[root@localhost ~]# virsh start GOS_1
error: Failed to start domain GOS_1
error: Cannot access storage file '/container/pool/TEST.qcow2' (as uid:107, gid:107): No such file or directory

Comment: It doesn't matter if you shut down from the guest or from libvirt. All that matters is that you actually shut down. Reboot isn't sufficient. But it seems from your error that perhaps you didn't remove the storage from the libvirt configuration after all?

Comment: I done virsh vol-delete option to remove the volume from host.  I didnt change the libvirt configuration file. When i issued a dumpxml after removing the vol [using vol-delete command] , the vm still showed those removed volumes in the xml.  But vol-delete should take care of  editing the configuration file from virsh? Confused about exact use of vol-delete command in this cae

Comment: `virsh vol-delete` only deletes storage. It doesn't change the configuration of any particular VM.

Comment: Sure. Got it. But another question is when I deleted the storage  and after that I  executed write using fio [ expecting a failure since storage got removed],  it succeeded!!!. There is no storage from host, but fio was able to write. How it worked? Is it mean the storage is not released even if we do virsh vol-delete command?

Comment: That's just how UNIX like systems have handled file deletion since the 1970s. If something still has the file open, it won't be really deleted until the process closes it.

Comment: Thanks! Perfect.
So If I  have to delete the  disk from guest as well, I need to remove storage using virsh vol-delete, then I have to edit the  vm configuration file as well? Or is there a single command or option i can use for getting the final result?